# Storing a function inside a variable destroys the "this" context

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to run this code:

```
public isDataValid(obj: any){
    let isCriteriaValid = function (){
      for(let element in obj){
        if(!this.isStringOrObjectValid(element)){
          return false
        }
      }
      return true
    }
    return (obj != undefined) ? isCriteriaValid() : false
}
```

A quick explanation:

Running this function checks to see if an object is valid by checking all of the elements in it.

I have an issue with the "this" context being sort of "erased".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: tldr: functions in JavaScript are “unbound”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a little thing called scope.  The scope isn't "erased", the "this" keyword is referring to a new scope.

The scope of the `isStringOrObjectValid` function is now the function it was declared in which is the local variable.  I fixed it by passing in the object that I wanted to run the function off of to the ternary statement.  Like this:

```
let isCriteriaValid = function (service){
  for(let element in obj){
    if(!service.isStringOrObjectValid(element)){
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
return (obj != undefined) ? isCriteriaValid(this) : false
```

If anyone has a better way, I'd be open to learning about this type of scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to pass the scope to a variable and then use that

```
public isDataValid(obj: any){
  **let that = this;**   
    let isCriteriaValid = function () {
        for (let element in obj) {
          if (!**that**.isStringOrObjectValid(element)) {
            return false
          }
        }
        return true
      }
      return (obj != undefined) ? isCriteriaValid() : false
    }
```

but really in this day and age you should be using an ES6 arrow function and the scope will be maintained ... something like this

```
public isDataValid2(obj: any) {
    let isCriteriaValid = () => {
      for (let element in obj) {        
        if (!this.isStringOrObjectValid(element)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    };

    return obj !== undefined ? isCriteriaValid() : false;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this.  Though why not pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: you're splitting hairs tbh and life is too short to worry about tiny differences in those 2 ways .... you should really be doing it in ES6 so I've updated my answer for this

Comment: Very cool, I've used this with subscribes like `() => {}` for complete but I didn't think of it this way.